# Swift Filter Array By Index Range

Tags: swift

I have an array, say with 100 items in it, and I want to filter out all the items between 20-30.

Something like this, but this isn't correct obviously:

```
myArray.filter_by_indices(20...30)
```

I searched and searched, and couldn't find an answer.

Comment: `array.removeSubrange(20...30)`?

Comment: You want to remove those items or keep those items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a filter. You can simply call `removeSubrange`.

```
myArray.removeSubrange(20..30)
```

And for the sake of completeness, here is an option using a filter:

```
myArray = myArray.enumerated().filter { $0.offset < 20 || $0.offset > 30 }.map { $0.element }
```